# $H^{1}(G,M)$ for an infinite cyclic group $G$

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be an infinite cyclic group with generator $t$, and $M$ be a $G-$module. I need help with the following problem (of MacLane's book Homology) : Show that

$$H^{1}(G,M)\cong M/L$$

where $L=\{tx-x:x\in M\}$

My aproach: by definition is $H^{1}(G,M)=Der(G,M)/InnDer(G,M)$. It is natural to define $\rho:Der(G,M)\rightarrow M/L$ by:

$$\rho(\phi)=\phi(t)+L, \text{for all} \ \phi\in Der(G,M)$$

It is easy to proof that $\rho$ is an homomorphism of groups such that $Ker(\rho)=InnDer(G,M)$ but I can't see why $\rho$ is an epimorphism. If $v+L\in M/L$, for $v\in M$, it is natural to think that $v+L=\rho(\phi)$ where $\phi$ is determinated by $\phi(t)=tv=(t-1)v+v$ but I can't proof that $\phi$ is a derivation.

Note: the solution of the problem must to be obtain without use projective resolutions.

Comment: If $v \in M$, define $\phi(t^n)=v+\ldots+t^{n-1}v$ for $n \geq 0$ and $\phi(t^{-n})=-t^{-n}\phi(t^n)$. It’s easy to see that $\phi(t^kt)=\phi(t^k)+t^k\phi(t)$, and by induction $\phi(t^{k+l})=\phi(t^k)+t^k\phi(t^l)$ for $l \geq 0$. And then this very equality, writing $k=(k+l)+(-l)$, shows the result for $l \leq 0$.

Comment: @Mindlack thanks for the help. Now I can see clearly.